# Is File.length platform and filesystem independant

Tags: java, file, filesystems, operating-system, nio

Image I catch a stream of the net and count how many bytes went through my hands, I write this stream to a file. Is the number of counted bytes guranteed to be equal to the file.length() result (after flushing etc...)?

If you look at the Windows Explorer it gives you some different numbers (size on disk, real size,...).

Is the java file.length free of any OS and filesystem extensions to the file?

The javadoc only says: `The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size on disk is how many bytes the file takes on the filesystem. It is not the file size. What `file.length()` returns is, as you quoted from the javadoc, how many bytes you can read from the file. So yes, it is platform independent.

> Is the number of counted bytes guranteed to be equal to the file.length() result

if you're reading bytes and writing bytes, without converting to strings, etc. Then yes.

Comment: "how many bytes you can read" the javadoc doesn't really say that in as clear words as you do :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
 number of counted bytes guranteed to be equal to the file.length()
```

I don't think so. Mostly no. It would depend on character encoding. Each character that you write in a file may take more than one byte of space.

Comment: no encoding is going on, I catch raw bytes over the net and write raw bytes to the filesystem. As also as a byte is defined as 8 bits there should be no expansion going on. I'm talking about extra information that the filesystem adds or compression build into the filesystem etc.

Comment: if reading and writing bytes, yes, ideally they should be equal. But once java hands over the file to the OS, it may add extra things.Most common difference is how new line is handled in windows and unix systems, \r\n and \n.

Comment: @RaviBhatt No. The OS does not change line terminators. What you write is what gets written.